# Which address to use for local TCP server?

Tags: c#, sockets, go, tcp, localhost

I'm writing a system where two programs will asynchronously communicate over a TCP socket. The client is written in golang, but the server might vary. I'm currently writing one in C#.

During development, I used

```go
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort("127.0.0.1", strconv.Itoa(d.port)))
```

for the client, and on the server I did:

```cs
this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
```

However, for production, I suspect that might not work in all cases. For example, the user might use IPv6. I also tried `localhost` on the server, but on Windows that doesn't seem to be the same as `127.0.0.1` by default (it has to be enabled, which is not an option).

Is there a more fool-proof way of running a local TCP server, that should work in all cases?

Comment: use 127.0.0.1. For all practical purposes it is always defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IPAddress.Loopback` is what you're looking for. You still have a separate address for IPv6, though - `IPAddress.IPv6Loopback`. The two correspond to `127.0.0.1` and `::1` respectively, by definition - it's part of the IP standard.

If you want to have the server available from other computers as well, `IPAddress.Any` (and `IPAddress.IPv6Any` for IPv6) binds to all the NICs on the system.

In general, there is no way to have a common solution that uses IPv4 and IPv6 "natively", since the two protocols are really entirely separate (with an IPv4 "fallback" in IPv6 - however, it isn't widely supported, and nobody really uses it). This is not a big deal on localhost, though - just try to bind `IPAddress.Loopback`, and if it fails, try `IPAddress.IPv6Loopback`.